# Setting proxy in Goutte

Tags: php, web-scraping, goutte

I've tried using Guzzle's docs to set proxy but it's not working. The official Github page for Goutte is pretty dead so can't find anything there.

Anyone know how to set a proxy?

This is what I've tried:

```
$client = new Client();
$client->setHeader('User-Agent', $user_agent);
$crawler = $client->request('GET', $request, ['proxy' => $proxy]);
```

Comment: Did you find any answer, I am facing same problem

Comment: Nope.  I just went back to php curl.  Works much better and less buggy.

Answer (score 3):

I have solved this problem =>

```
    $url = 'https://api.myip.com';
    $client = new \Goutte\Client;
    $client->setClient(new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['proxy' => 'http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080']));
    $get_html = $client->request('GET', $url)->html();
    var_dump($get_html);
```

Comment: [Check this issue](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte/issues/220#issuecomment-595518077) Seems for new versions need another config. Tested with PHPUnit 9.5.2

Answer (score 2):

You thinking rigth, but in Goutte\Client::doRequest(), when create Guzzle client

```
$guzzleRequest = $this->getClient()->createRequest(
        $request->getMethod(),
        $request->getUri(),
        $headers,
        $body
);
```

options are not passed when create request object. So, if you want to use a proxy, then override the class Goutte\Client, the method doRequest(), and replace this code on

```
$guzzleRequest = $this->getClient()->createRequest(
        $request->getMethod(),
        $request->getUri(),
        $headers,
        $body,
        $request->getParameters()
);
```

Example overriding class:

```
<?php

namespace igancev\override;

class Client extends \Goutte\Client
{
    protected function doRequest($request)
    {
        $headers = array();
        foreach ($request->getServer() as $key => $val) {
            $key = implode('-', array_map('ucfirst', explode('-', strtolower(str_replace(array('_', 'HTTP-'), array('-', ''), $key)))));
            if (!isset($headers[$key])) {
                $headers[$key] = $val;
            }
        }

        $body = null;
        if (!in_array($request->getMethod(), array('GET','HEAD'))) {
            if (null !== $request->getContent()) {
                $body = $request->getContent();
            } else {
                $body = $request->getParameters();
            }
        }

        $guzzleRequest = $this->getClient()->createRequest(
            $request->getMethod(),
            $request->getUri(),
            $headers,
            $body,
            $request->getParameters()
        );

        foreach ($this->headers as $name => $value) {
            $guzzleRequest->setHeader($name, $value);
        }

        if ($this->auth !== null) {
            $guzzleRequest->setAuth(
                $this->auth['user'],
                $this->auth['password'],
                $this->auth['type']
            );
        }

        foreach ($this->getCookieJar()->allRawValues($request->getUri()) as $name => $value) {
            $guzzleRequest->addCookie($name, $value);
        }

        if ('POST' == $request->getMethod() || 'PUT' == $request->getMethod()) {
            $this->addPostFiles($guzzleRequest, $request->getFiles());
        }

        $guzzleRequest->getParams()->set('redirect.disable', true);
        $curlOptions = $guzzleRequest->getCurlOptions();

        if (!$curlOptions->hasKey(CURLOPT_TIMEOUT)) {
            $curlOptions->set(CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
        }

        // Let BrowserKit handle redirects
        try {
            $response = $guzzleRequest->send();
        } catch (CurlException $e) {
            if (!strpos($e->getMessage(), 'redirects')) {
                throw $e;
            }

            $response = $e->getResponse();
        } catch (BadResponseException $e) {
            $response = $e->getResponse();
        }

        return $this->createResponse($response);
    }
}
```

And try send request

```
$client = new \igancev\override\Client();
$proxy = 'http://149.56.85.17:8080'; // free proxy example
$crawler = $client->request('GET', $request, ['proxy' => $proxy]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can directly use in Goutte or Guzzle Request

```
$proxy = 'xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx';

$goutte = new GoutteClient();
echo $goutte->request('GET', 'https://example.com/', ['proxy' => $proxy])->html();
```

Use Same method in Guzzle

```
$Guzzle = new Client();
$GuzzleResponse = $Guzzle->request('GET', 'https://example.com/', ['proxy' => $proxy]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set a custom `GuzzleClient` and assign it to `Goutte` client.
When `Guzzle` makes the request through `Goutte` uses the default config. That config is passed in the `Guzzle` construct.

```
$guzzle = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['proxy' => 'http://192.168.1.1:8080']);
$goutte = new \Goutte\Client();
$goutte->setClient($guzzle);
$crawler = $goutte->request($method, $url);
```

Answer (score 1):

**For recent versions use:**

Goutte Client instance (which extends Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\HttpBrowser)

```php
use Symfony\Component\HttpClient\HttpClient;
use Goutte\Client;

$client = new Client(HttpClient::create(['proxy' => 'http://xx.xx.xx.xx:80']));
...
```