# Using Goutte with proxies - general Workflow

Tags: php, proxy, goutte

I'm writing a little spider to crawl a local newspaper's website. I am working with Goutte which I'm new to. I would like to use a random proxy every time I crawl the site. As I am fairly new to proxies too, I have two questions:

1.) How do I set up Goutte to use a proxy?
2.) How do I set up a proxy to work with my script?

Unluckily I wasn't able to find some useful advice via google, so thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: you might find some help here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35806758/setting-proxy-in-goutte/42317846#42317846