# I always get an error when trying to create a crawler in goutte

Tags: php, symfony, web-scraping, goutte

The error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Return value of
> Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler::createSubCrawler() must be an
> instance of Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\object, instance of
> Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler returned in
> /Users/local/web.com/vendor/symfony/dom-crawler/Crawler.php:1215 Stack
> trace:
> #0 /Users/local/web.com/vendor/symfony/dom-crawler/Crawler.php(969): Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler->createSubCrawler(NULL)
> #1 /Users/local/web.com/vendor/symfony/dom-crawler/Crawler.php(189): Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler->filterRelativeXPath('descendant-or-s...')
> #2 /Users/local/web.com/vendor/symfony/dom-crawler/Crawler.php(169): Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler->addHtmlContent('', 'utf-8')
> #3 /Users/local/web.com/vendor/symfony/browser-kit/Client.php(535): Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler->addContent('', 'text/html;
> char...')
> #4 /Users/local/web.com/vendor/symfony/browser-kit/Client.php(425): Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Client->createCrawlerFromContent('https://stackov...',
> '', 'text/html; c in
> /Users/local/web.com/vendor/symfony/dom-crawler/Crawler.php on line
> 1215

here is my code:

```
$guzzle = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['proxy' => 'http://91.205.174.26:80']);
$goutte = new \Goutte\Client();
$goutte->setClient($guzzle);
$crawler = $goutte->request('GET', 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35806758/setting-proxy-in-goutte');
```

the last line is the line that is giving the error. I have tried lots of things like changing `$goutte = new \Goutte\Client();` to `$client = \Symfony\Component\Panther\Client::createChromeClient();` which is using panther to create a client because everything works fine when I use panther, but when I integrate panther and other libraries I get this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method
> Symfony\Component\Panther\Client::setClient()

none of the methods have worked.

Does anyone know a solution?